# Generating secret URLs for a resource in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I've created a task management app that consists of `lists` and `tasks`. Users can only view their own lists and tasks. I would like to add the ability for a user to share a `list` if they like. Here are the steps I would like to accomplish:

1. User clicks a link from /list/show to share the list
2. User receives a secret URL to share: myapp.com/lists/1/23534512345234523 or whatever.
3. Secret URL redirects to a view other than /lists/show. Something like /lists/1/23534512345234523 which would be routed to /lists/secret_show or whatev.
4. Only users who have that url can see the information on that page.

Hope that is making sense. I imagine I would have to update the `list` record with a unique token to list.token. Then I would some how have to recieve the incoming URL and through a new action

lists#secret_share

```
def secret_share
 ...
end
```

Where I filtered for the list record by list.token and routed to secret_share. Then perhaps in the view I could simply restrict the view by the presence of the token in the URL.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever "secret URL" you hand out should not redirect to the real URL or you're going to create all kinds of opportunities for information leakage. It should be a strictly alternate URL.

Using routing for this seems like a good idea instead of using a separate controller. In your route you might want to pass an additional parameter to indicate this is a "secret" URL, like `:secret => true` where the value in question is something that cannot be submitted by the user to fake things out. User parameters are always strings, for instance, so using `true` should be a safe alternative.

This special parameter might disable access checking on your controller so that the page can be viewed by people that don't normally have access. You could also show a different layout using the `layout` method in your controller.